# Classnotfound for jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I created a jar, which references libraries. Classpath is set in manifest file. It works fine on my pc.
If I deploy jar and lib Folder to other pc's there is an classnotfound exception. Apparently the libraries (e.g. log4j) are not found.
What could be a reason, if not manifest file or lib Directory??

This is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_101-b14 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: dq.dqreport.Main
Class-Path: ../lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar ../lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar 
 ../lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar ../lib/db2jcc.jar ../lib/db2jcc4.jar
  ../lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar ../lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar ../lib/junit-
 4.12.jar ../lib/junit-4.7.jar ../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar ../lib/poi-3.13
 -20150929.jar ../lib/poi-examples-3.13-20150929.jar ../lib/poi-excela
 nt-3.13-20150929.jar ../lib/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar ../lib/poi-oo
 xml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar ../lib/poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar
  ../lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

Comment: Can you please post what exactly error message saying ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run with java -verbose option to check which path system class loader trying to load. I guess you need to use set classpath=.;..; before running the application.

Answer (score 1):

The jar file and the lib folder should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are the jar file and lib folder located in the same directory?